# Laravel isDirty method mass assignment

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

My code is saving data of only one `field(efirst)` if it's changed by the isDirty() method, and it's working correctly. How can I achieve the same result if I have ten fields without writing each field name?

**Controller:**

```php
public function update(TeacherRequest $request, $id)
{
    $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
    $teacher->efirst = $request->efirst;

    if ($teacher->isDirty()) {
        $new_data = $teacher->efirst;
        $old_data = $teacher->getOriginal('efirst');

        if ($teacher->save()) {
            $teacher->update($request->except('qual_id', 'id', 'profile_pic'));

            DB::table('teacher_logs')->insert(
                [
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'teacher_id' => $teacher->id,
                    'old_value' => $old_data,
                    'new_value' => $new_data,
                ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What result are you talking about?

Comment: @lagbox i want to check if any fields is changed or not.

Comment: that is what `isDirty` does, checks to see if the model's attributes have been modified

Comment: @lagbox i am doing it to check one field in above code, how can i do same if i have 5 fields? i will have to type each?

Comment: [Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) - `fill`

Comment: @lagbox how is dirty will work with mass assignment? below answer suggested to use foreach loop.

Comment: do you know what mass assignment is? don't mean that to be rude, just figuring some baseline here

Comment: @lagbox i read in documentation

Comment: @lagbox i am using request->all(); to save and update , i guess that's mass assignment.

Comment: @lagbox if you see my code, i have used, $teacher->update($request->except('qual_id','id','profile_pic')); // that's also mass assignment to update each field,

Comment: I honestly dont know what you are trying to achieve, the way you are inserting into `teacher_logs` would seem you have no way to differentiate what field was changed

Comment: but it's inserting efirst old value and new value. just looking for mass assignment in this case, or you can suggest what better method would be.

Comment: sorry I still have no clue what you are trying to achieve ... good luck

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to write `$teacher->field = $request->value;` a bunch of times, you may use a loop:

```
foreach($request->except("_token") AS $field => $value){
  $teacher->{$field} = $value;
}

if($teacher->isDirty()){
  $new_data = [];
  $old_data = [];
  foreach($request->except("_token") AS $field => $value){
    $new_data[$field] = $value;
    $old_data[$field] = $teacher->getOriginal($field);
  }
}
```

Note: You'll need to convert `$new_data` and `$old_data` to arrays so you can reference each field and value properly, and do some additional logic on the insert of your `teacher_logs` table to handle, but that should give you an idea.